# Argument 1 passed to SymfonyFixturesLoader::addFixture() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Full error - `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Loader\SymfonyFixturesLoader::addFixture() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface, instance of Abstrat\OAuthBundle\Controller\TokenController given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/Loader/SymfonyFixturesLoader.php on line 36 in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/Loader/SymfonyFixturesLoader.php on line 40`

I'm setting up a new Symfony 3.4 API server as i'm migrating code across from an old Symfony 2.7 API server. I have included a couple of custom bundles via composer, with Abstrat\OAuthBundle being one of them (see error in title as this bundle seems to be what's causing the problem)

I haven't created any bundles in ./src yet as I want to get the include libraries working before hand

I can't see why the Abstrat\OAuthBundle that i'm including is being passed to addFixture()

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: This was due to the services.yml in the OAuthBundle. I guess I need to update it to support Symfony 3.4 better as it was originally written for Symfony 2.7

`services:
  abstrat.oauth.token_controller:
    class: Abstrat\OAuthBundle\Controller\TokenController
    arguments: ['@fos_oauth_server.server']
    calls:
      - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
    tags: [doctrine.fixture.orm]`

Comment: So does that solve your problem? If it does, cool! Make sure to answer your own question so that others searching for a similar message can also find the answer.